# Python script does not work when started via osascript

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, errno, osascript

Ok, so when I run this command:

```
sudo python3.5 /path/to/my/script.py
```

It executes fine and returns:

> select user:
>
> 1. Guest
> 2. My username
>
>    Choose the account that needs cleaning up (enter corresponding number):

After which I enter "2", press enter and the script runs great.

However, when I run:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "python3.5 /Path/to/my/script.py" with administrator privileges'
```

I get the expected pop-up screen in which to enter my sudo-password, but afterwards it throws out the error:

> OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor (1)needs cleaning up (enter
>   corresponding number):")

Anyone has any idea on this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS; some background as to why I need this method --> I am using a pre-script (also written in python) from which myscript.py needs to be executed. My prescript.py ***does not*** need administrator privileges. Sometimes however, it will be required to call myscript.py which ***does*** need administrative privileges. Since I do not want to hard-code my sudo-password into any of my scripts I want to get a pop-up box asking me for it. I figured, telling my pre-script.py to run subprocess.Popen([]) on the osascript command I mentioned above would do the trick. However, for that, I first need to get the osascript command to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so I figured this one out myself. As expected it had to do with privileges. Somehow `"do shell script"` is run via other privileges then just entering the command in terminal. And `"sudo command"` in terminal does not equal (fully) to `"do shell script [script] with administrator privileges"`.

For me, what fixed it, was navigating to:

System Preferences --> Security and Privacy --> Privacy tab --> Accessibility

And then dragging Python.app and Terminal.app to that window (you might need to unlock it first by pressing on the little lock in the lower-left corner of that window).